# Describing a distance vector in space

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have two points in cartesian coordinates $P_1 = (1,0,2)$ and $P_2 =(0,2,1)$ and need the distance vector from $P_1$ to point $P_2$. The vector from origin to $P_1$ is defined as $\textbf{R}$ while the vector from origin to point $P_2$ is defined as $\textbf{R'}$. The vector I am looking for is then $\textbf{R-R'}$ between the first and the second one in space. I have forgotten linear algebra a bit so I am not sure of the proper way of doing it. Could you please help me out?

Is this right?

$$ \textbf{R} = (1,0,2) \\ \textbf{R'} = (0,2,1) \\ \textbf{R-R'} = (1,0,2) - (0,2,1) = (1,-2,1) $$

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote is the opposite: the vector from $P_2$ to $P_1$. The vector from $P_1$ to $P_2$ will be $$\mathbf{R’} -\mathbf R =(-1,2,-1)$$